# Using a UIView as a Controller

Tags: ios, uiview, controller, structure

right now I'm concerning the structure of my App. I thought of subclassing UIView to make a "root view" that will perform as a Controller of the main flow of the app. So the subclass of UIView will have methods that will e.g. be invoked by Subviews, that perform the changes of the content, that is shown. Would you say this is a bad structure (/style) of programming, and if so, why is it bad or not elegant?
Thanks for any Help :)

sh4kesbeer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like a UIViewController, smells like a UIViewController, tastes like a UIViewController. So why not use a UIViewController?

Comment: Hi, thx for your answer, but i dont get the sense of a UIViewController, maybe i have to work into that topic a bit more :)

Comment: A UIViewController is a container class that can contain one or more UIView objects - UILabel, UIButton, etc. It handles generic events for you, like device orientation for example. Just create a project and add a UIViewController class in it to get a sense of what it does for you; also, Apple has good docs on it.

Answer (score 0):

Views must show something to the user; controllers must implement application logic.
It means that is the controller that choose which view must be shown to the user.

If you want to study something more take a look to the [apple documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/general/conceptual/CocoaEncyclopedia/Model-View-Controller/Model-View-Controller.html) or what [wikipedia says](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model-View-Controller).

Answer (score 0):

There's no logical difference of using UIView standalone or wrapped into UIViewController other than you are not using all the nice patterns designed for UIViewControllers like a standard callbacks, navController integration, tabBarController support, etc. Also makes your code listings larger and harder to read/understand.

However here's the main point, from the OOP perspective you are letting down encapsulation level affecting messaging as well. And now meet the killer: you are making `C` at `MVC` as small as it is barely visible from some points of view.

From my experience view based projects start just fine and then all kind of difficulties come to your door forcing you to think about refactoring which makes you to invent view controllers from scratch.